# Would setInterval block/interfere with node.js/express HTTP server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

- I have a express http server running on Ubuntu
- It does some `app.get/post calls` and talks to `mongoDB`.

Now I need to run standalone javascript periodically which will talk to the same mongoDB.

So, in `app.js`, I plan to do:

```
app.get()
app.post()
...
app.listen(3443);

setInterval(function () {
  runStandAloneScript();  
}, 86400); 

function runStandAloneScript() {
    // makes http calls to local server and mongodb locally
}
```

My question would this block/interfere `app.get/post` calls in any way?

Comment: If `runStandAloneScript` takes a nontrivial amount of time to complete, then yes, it could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will block your server if `runStandAloneScript` is synchronous, and will block it for as long as the method runs.

```
setInterval(function () {
  runStandAloneScript();
}, 86400); 

function runStandAloneScript() {
   sleepSync(5); // 5 seconds sleep, blocking
}
```

The previous script will block the server for 5 seconds, every 86400 seconds, preventing any request to be processed.

If you perform some non blocking I/O in `runStandAloneScript` your server will function normally.

```
function runStandAloneScript() {
   return fs.readFile('./tmp/some-file.txt');
}
```

By default, file system operations, database calls, and http requests are always asynchronous in Node.js, so unless you're running some heavy computations or using the synchronous version of these methods, such as `fs.readFileSync`, your server won't be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

It will not get blocked unless your functions in [setInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args) are synchronous.

Basically, in your code, you are calling runStandAloneScript() for every 86400 milli seconds. Once the timer is elapsed it will perform the runStandAloneScript() and then it will keep the timer again and this process continues.

Having said, if the runStandAloneScript() is synchronous then it will block the server. So, use asynchronous functions such that your server handles the request appropriately or use the child process mechanism based on the scenario.